# add row number based on tbname filed using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

input file

```
tbname id department 
xyz    20 cic 
xyz    21 csp 
xyz    22 cpz 
abc    25 cis 
abc    26 cta 
abc    27 tec
```

output should look like this ..

```
tbname id department 
xyz    20 cic          1 
xyz    21 csp          2 
xyz    22 cpz          3 
abc    25 cis          1 
abc    26 cta          2 
abc    27 tec          3
```

All fields are separated by a tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really trivial in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$0=$0"\t"++a[$1]}1' file
tbname id department 
xyz    20 cic   1
xyz    21 csp   2
xyz    22 cpz   3
abc    25 cis   1
abc    26 cta   2
abc    27 tec   3
```